# Data table sends wrong data to backing bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have a data-table (p:datatable) with filters and an action button on each row. Now when I click on action button, wrong data is passed to the bean.

Actually when Edit button is clicked, startupdate method of the bean is called and an argument is passed to it.

In normal cases, without any filter, right employee gets passes and the dialog box opens and shows correct values. However when I apply filter, It's always the first row which gets passed and the dialog box opens and show details of the employee of first row.

I do have rowKey set.

```
    <h:form id="wrapform">
<p:dataTable style="margin-top:20px" widgetVar="emptable" id="empdata" var="emp" rowKey="#{emp.empdto.id}" value="#{employeeMaintainanceController.allUsersWithDetails}" filteredValue="#{employeeMaintainanceController.allUsersWithDetails_filtered}">

    <f:facet name="header">
        <p:outputPanel>
            <h:outputText value="Search in any column:" />
            <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="emptable.filter()" style="width:150px; margin-left: 10px;" />
            </p:outputPanel>
                </f:facet>

    <p:column headerText="Employee-Id" filterBy="#{emp.userdto.id}" filterMatchMode="contains">
        <h:outputText value="#{emp.userdto.id}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="First Name" filterBy="#{emp.userdto.firstName}" filterMatchMode="contains">
        <h:outputText value="#{emp.userdto.firstName}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Last Name" filterBy="#{emp.userdto.lastName}" filterMatchMode="contains">
        <h:outputText value="#{emp.userdto.lastName}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="E-mail">
        <h:outputText value="#{emp.userdto.email}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Date of Joining">
        <h:outputText value="#{emp.empdto.doj}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Team" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="#{teamMaintainanceController.getTeamById(emp.empdto.teamid)}">
        <h:outputText value="#{teamMaintainanceController.getTeamById(emp.empdto.teamid)}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Office" filterBy="#{employeeMaintainanceController.getLocName(emp.userdto.primaryOfficeSeq)}" filterMatchMode="contains">
        <h:outputText value="#{employeeMaintainanceController.getLocName(emp.userdto.primaryOfficeSeq)}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Is Active?">
        <h:outputText value="#{(emp.empdto.dor == null)?'Active':'Already Resigned'}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Edit">
         <p:commandButton value="Edit/Move/Delete"
                title="Edit"
                actionListener="#{employeeMaintainanceController.startUpdate(emp)}"
                ajax="true" process="@this" oncomplete="dlg2.show();" update=":entryform"/>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
</h:form>

<p:dialog header="Change Employee Details, Move him to different Teams, Transfer him to different Locations" widgetVar="dlg2" modal="true" >
    <h:form id="entryform">
    <table id="empdatatable">
    <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true"/>
            <tr><td><p:outputLabel for="searchedid" value="ID" rendered="#{employeeMaintainanceController.wrapemp !=null}"></p:outputLabel></td><td><h:outputText id="searchedid" value="#{employeeMaintainanceController.wrapemp.userdto.id}"></h:outputText></td></tr>
            <tr><td><p:outputLabel for="searchedfname" value="First Name" rendered="#{employeeMaintainanceController.wrapemp !=null}"></p:outputLabel></td><td><h:outputText id="searchedfname" value="#{employeeMaintainanceController.wrapemp.userdto.firstName}"></h:outputText></td></tr>
            <tr><td><p:outputLabel for="searchedlname" value="Last Name" rendered="#{employeeMaintainanceController.wrapemp !=null}"></p:outputLabel></td><td><h:outputText id="searchedlname" value="#{employeeMaintainanceController.wrapemp.userdto.lastName}"></h:outputText></td></tr>
            <tr><td><p:outputLabel for="searchedemail" value="E-Mail" rendered="#{employeeMaintainanceController.wrapemp !=null}"></p:outputLabel></td><td><h:outputText id="searchedemail" value="#{employeeMaintainanceController.wrapemp.userdto.email}"></h:outputText></td></tr>
            <tr><td><p:outputLabel for="loc" value="Office Location" rendered="#{employeeMaintainanceController.wrapemp !=null}"></p:outputLabel></td><td><p:selectOneMenu id="loc" value="#{employeeMaintainanceController.wrapemp.userdto.primaryOfficeSeq}" rendered="#{employeeMaintainanceController.wrapemp !=null}">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="-1" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{employeeMaintainanceController.officeList}" var="theme" itemLabel="#{theme.name}" itemValue="#{theme.seq}"/>
            </p:selectOneMenu></td></tr>
           <tr><td><p:outputLabel for="searcheddoj" value="Date Of Joining" rendered="#{employeeMaintainanceController.wrapemp !=null}"></p:outputLabel></td><td><h:outputText id="searcheddoj" value="#{employeeMaintainanceController.wrapemp.empdto.doj}"></h:outputText></td></tr>
            <tr><td><p:outputLabel for="cal1" value="Date Of Resignation" rendered="#{employeeMaintainanceController.wrapemp !=null}"></p:outputLabel></td><td><p:calendar id="cal1" value="#{employeeMaintainanceController.wrapemp.empdto.dor}" rendered="#{employeeMaintainanceController.wrapemp !=null}" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td><p:outputLabel for="chk_isadmin" value="IS Admin?" rendered="#{employeeMaintainanceController.wrapemp !=null}"></p:outputLabel></td><td><p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="chk_isadmin" value="#{employeeMaintainanceController.isadmin}" rendered="#{employeeMaintainanceController.wrapemp !=null}"></p:selectBooleanCheckbox> </td></tr>
            <tr><td><p:outputLabel for="sel_team" value="TeamName" rendered="#{employeeMaintainanceController.wrapemp !=null}"></p:outputLabel></td><td><p:selectOneMenu id="sel_team" value="#{employeeMaintainanceController.wrapemp.empdto.teamid}" rendered="#{employeeMaintainanceController.wrapemp !=null}">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="-1" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{teamMaintainanceController.allTeams}" var="theme" itemLabel="#{theme.name}" itemValue="#{theme.id}"/>
            </p:selectOneMenu></td></tr>
            <tr><td><p:commandButton value="Edit" ajax="false" actionListener="#{employeeMaintainanceController.updateemp}" update=":wrapform" oncomplete="dlg2.hide();" rendered="#{employeeMaintainanceController.wrapemp !=null}"></p:commandButton></td><td><p:commandButton value="Delete This Employee" ajax="false" actionListener="#{employeeMaintainanceController.deleteemp}" update=":wrapform" oncomplete="dlg2.hide();" rendered="#{employeeMaintainanceController.wrapemp !=null}"></p:commandButton></td></tr>
        </table>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

**UPDATE**
The problems more weird. The problem appears only when the number of filtered row is just one. Anything else and it works fine.

Comment: try using  filteredValue="#{employeeMaintainanceController.allUsersWithDetails}"

Comment: already tried it, after filtering datatable become blank. I used a workaround and used  f:param which works, however i still don't know, why it doesn't work. I forgot to add that I have primefaces 3.4. Is it because of that?